# Odd results from Bash-4 recursion

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, recursion

I devised a simple test to see how Bash behaves with recursion, and I do not understand the results.

Test:

1. Assign a global variable `X` in the shell
2. Create a function `f()` that assigns a variable `local X` of the same name
3. Assign `local X` the value of the global `X` i.e. `local X=$X`
4. Recurse this function a few times and check whether, on each recursion, it uses the global `X` or the `local X` from the previous turn of the function

I expected one of two outcomes:

- On each recursion, the `local X` from the previous `f()` would be the new "global" `X`, i.e. the `X` in the next-up scope, which would indicate that each recursion creates a new scope beneath the previous scope
- On each recursion, the previous `local X` value would be forgotten, and each new `local X=$X` would simply reassign the value of the global `X` I initially assigned. This would indicate that Bash creates adjacent scopes.

I didn't get any of these. I got something weird. Below is the copy-paste from the terminal.

I assign a global variable in the shell:

```
user@ubuntu-zesty:~$ X=1
```

I create a function `f()` in the shell that creates `local X`, assigns the value of the global `X` to it, enters a while loop, adds 1 to `local X` (I assume its the local one), prints the new `local X` value, and calls itself. Repeat 5 or 6 times.

```
user@ubuntu-zesty:~$ f() { local X=$X; while [ $X -lt 6 ]; do X=$(( $X + 1 )); echo $X; sleep 1; f; done; }
```

Then I call `f()`, and the output is just baffling.

```
user@ubuntu-zesty:~$ f
2
3
4
5
6
6
5
6
6
4
5
6
6
5
6
6
3
4
5
6
6
5
6
6
4
5
6
6
5
6
6
```

At this point it exited on its own. And as expected the global `X` was unaffected.

```
user@ubuntu-zesty:~$ echo $X
1
```

So what's going on here? Is it sometimes using the global `X`, sometimes the `local X`? Please if you know what's going on here don't spare me the gory details.

Lastly, just for fun, a graph of the output:

```
 1 ==
 2 ===
 3 ====
 4 =====
 5 ======
 6 ======
 7 =====
 8 ======
 9 ======
10 ====
11 =====
12 ======
13 ======
14 =====
15 ======
16 ======
17 ===
18 ====
19 =====
20 ======
21 ======
22 =====
23 ======
24 ======
25 ====
26 =====
27 ======
28 ======
29 =====
30 ======
31 ======
```

Specs:

- Bash-4.4.5(1)-release
- x86_64 Ubuntu Zesty
- Linux kernel 4.10.0-17-generic
- VMware Workstation 12 virtual machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best way to visualize *dynamic scoping* as perfectly explained by @chepner in his answer is to modify your function slightly:

```
function f() { 
  local X="$X"
  while [ "$X" -lt 6 ]; do 
    X=$((X + 1))
    echo "${FUNCNAME[*]}" "$X" # This will print the call stack
    sleep 1
    f
  done
}
```

And see how the values increase: if you follow the output columns, you can debug what happens at each level.

```
$ f
f f f f f 2
f f f f f f 3
f f f f f f f 4
f f f f f f f f 5
f f f f f f f f f 6
f f f f f f f f 6
f f f f f f f 5
f f f f f f f f 6
f f f f f f f 6
f f f f f f 4
f f f f f f f 5
f f f f f f f f 6
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`bash` is *dynamically* scoped, not statically (aka lexically) scoped. That means when you execute the line `local X=$X`, you are not getting the value of `$X` based on the value assigned at the global lexical scope, but the value that exists in the closest runtime scope, namely the value in the scope from which `f` was *called*. This means that the a local value is not just visible in the function call, but from any call made from there.

Note that this is not specific to recursion.

```
$ X=3
$ foo () { local X=5; bar; }
$ bar () { echo $X; }
$ bar
3
$ foo
5
$ echo $X
3
```

Comment: Okay that is closest to my first hypothesis, but it isn't obvious how it explains the odd output. I'll need to sit down later and think though @ikkachu and your answers. (also thanks for fixing my post)

Answer (score 1):

There are 31 output lines, which is suspiciously the same as 2<sup>5</sup>-1. What seems to happen is that every iteration of the loop copies the function, with the value of `X` being the same as it was at that point.

So on every level the function completes the remaining part of the loop twice creating a binary tree. Visually the outermost parts would look like this:

```
4
+--5
|  +--6 
|  +--6
+--5
   +--6 
   +--6
```

(Isn't this your first suggestion? I'm not exactly sure.)

This produces the same result (run with `f 1`), but passes the value explicitly as an argument to the lower level.

```
f() { 
  local X=$1;
  while [ $X -lt 6 ]; do
     X=$(( $X + 1 ));
     echo $X;
     f $X;
  done; 
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, I'll need to sit down later and work though this.

Answer (score 1):

Lets make the function quite more verbose, and just use 4 as the limit.
You can try with 6.

Watch the exits !!

```
#!/bin/bash
depth=0
f() {
    echo "depth =======$((++depth))"
    echo "Received     $X"
    local X=$X;
    while (( X < 4 )); do
    (( X++ ));
    echo "Calling with $X";
    #sleep 1;
    f;
    done;
    echo "exit    with $X depth $((depth--))"
}

X=1
f
echo "final depth is $depth"
```

Running it will show exactly what happens:

```
$ ./script
depth =======1
Received     1
Calling with 2
depth =======2
Received     2
Calling with 3
depth =======3
Received     3
Calling with 4
depth =======4
Received     4
exit    with 4 depth 4
exit    with 4 depth 3
Calling with 4
depth =======3
Received     4
exit    with 4 depth 3
exit    with 4 depth 2
Calling with 3
depth =======2
Received     3
Calling with 4
depth =======3
Received     4
exit    with 4 depth 3
exit    with 4 depth 2
Calling with 4
depth =======2
Received     4
exit    with 4 depth 2
exit    with 4 depth 1
final depth is 0
```